# Dropbox API v2 error message

Tags: dropbox-api

When trying to get a delta result/cursor in the Java API:

```
client.files.listFolderBuilder(BASE_DIR).recursive(true).start();
```

I get the following error message:

```
com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles$ListFolderException: Exception in list_folder: ListFolderError.{".tag":"path","path":{".tag":"other"}}
```

As far as I can tell it doesn't really say what is wrong. Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason was that my BASE_DIR ended with a slash. Removing the trailing slash of the path seems to have fixed the problem.